# Remove duplicate menu bar icons in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, menu-bar

When I upgraded to macOS Sierra, a lot of my menu bar icons were duplicated. This included time, wifi, AirPlay, and Notification Center. I've been able to remove all of them *except* for Notification Center.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Drat... shortly after I posted this I found a way to kill off the SystemUIServer which was just the kick it needed.

```
killall -KILL SystemUIServer
```

PS: I searched before I posted originally. :)